# How to get final verdict out of all returns in Python in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Sorry, for a stupid question.
Let's say I want to compare elements of two lists using for loop. Now I wrote:-

```
for i in range(10):
     if a[i] == b[i]:
         print('True')
     else:
         print('False')
```

where a and b are two list.

Now I will get 10 outputs which will be either true or false. What I want is, if all of them are true then only True is printed and if any of them is false then false is printed (True or False printed only once).

This is just an example, I want to use this method for some other question and that too using for loop.

Please help.

Comment: what happens if some are true and some are false?

Comment: @Jim "if any are False, print False" should answer that

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard is some are true and some are false then the output should be False. True must be printed only if all are true

Answer (score 1):

If `a` and `b` contain "primitive" (strings, floats, integers, etc) you don't even need to have an element-wise comparison. `a == b` will do.

This will also work if `a` and `b` contain instances of an arbitrary class that implements `__eq__`.

Otherwise, this can be achieved by combining [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) and a generator expression in a fairly readable single line:

```
print(all(a_elem == b_elem for a_elem, b_elem in zip(a, b)))
```

Note that if the lists contain instances of an arbitrary class, that class should still implement `__eq__`.

`all` is [short-circuited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). It will stop as soon as it finds a pair `a_elem, b_elem`

where `a_elem != b_elem` and returns the boolean `False`.

If for some *odd* reason you would like the get the strings `'True'` or `'False'` you can convert the return value of `all` to a string:

```
print(str(all(a_elem == b_elem for a_elem, b_elem in zip(a, b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of what you want above would be written as:

```
if all([a[i] == b[i] for i in range(10)]):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

This would be comparable to:

```
flag = True
for i in range(10):
    flag = flag and a[i] == b[i]  # or flag &= a[i] == b[i] # since bool's are essentially binary
if flag:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

A function with proper bounds checking would be:

```
def compare_lists(a, b, N):
    if len(a) >= N <= len(b):
        return all([a[i] == b[i] for i in range(N)])
    else:
        print('Oops!')
```

The built-in `all()` function looks at the list of arguments passed and returns True only of all of them are True. Consider it a big 'AND' function.

You can daisy-chain comparison operations, so `0 < N < 10` works instead of having to write `0 < N and N < 10`.

The [ blah for blah in blah] is a very powerful concept called list comprehension, which allows you to write compact code.  for example, if you have a list `nums = [1, 2, 3]`, you could make a list of squares with `[i*i for i in nums]`, which would give you `[1, 4, 9]`.